# How do I achieve same effect without using attribute on $watch

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I do not understand the example given here http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. It is a timer that updates datetime every second.

```
    angular.module('docsTimeDirective', [])
    .controller('Ctrl2', function($scope) {
      $scope.format = 'M/d/yy h:mm:ss a';
    })
  .directive('myCurrentTime', function($timeout, dateFilter) {

    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
      var format,
          timeoutId;

      function updateTime() {
        element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), format));
      }

      scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
        format = value;
        updateTime();
      });

      function scheduleUpdate() {
        // save the timeoutId for canceling
        timeoutId = $timeout(function() {
          updateTime(); // update DOM
          scheduleUpdate(); // schedule the next update
        }, 1000);
      }

      element.on('$destroy', function() {
        $timeout.cancel(timeoutId);
      });

      // start the UI update process.
      scheduleUpdate();
    }

    return {
      link: link
    };
  });
```

and the Html looks like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="docsTimeDirective">
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Ctrl2">
      Date format: <input ng-model="format"> <hr/>
      Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to understand how to convert `Current time is: <span my-current-time="format"></span>` to `<my-current-time></my-current-time>` and encapsulate all the stuff. In particular, what should I do to this line

```
scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
  format = value;
  updateTime();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your trying to achieve the following [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/d7TqWbYhN89pDV5r2aRh?p=preview).

You need to:
`restrict:'E' // element`

and then

`change attrs.myCurrentTime to attrs.format for example`

that you get

`<my-current-time format="format"></my-current-time>`

#### EDIT

Check the updated [**plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/d7TqWbYhN89pDV5r2aRh?p=preview)

you can remove the watch altogether and just include `scope.format` `element.text(dateFilter(new Date(), scope.format));`

inside of the `updateTime` method

remember that when the user updates the format variable (a property of the scope) it also updates inside the directive.

Comment: This is very awesome! I am curious if it's possible to not use attribute on the tag at all.

Comment: are you keeping the input box? or you just want an element current time?

Comment: Yea I want to keep the input box, and somehow watch the input without using attribute.